# Get information from publishItem to publish end in sitecore

Tags: solr, sitecore

I got a setup with sitecore and solr.
Im looking to gather information (the different TemplatesIds) in publishItem, and then when the publish has ended, call solr with the names which needs to be reindex.

Ive managed to get all the template IDs both using PublishItemProcessor and as a publish:itemProcessed event, where i store the template ids in the PublishContext.CustomData as a Hashset. 
But how can i, when the publishing is done get this information i've gathered during publishing? I want to call solr, once, and only once, after everything is published, with information gathered during the publishing.

Hope this makes sense guys, please help out.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to make a hack to reindex indexes after a publishing.

Sitecore has out of the box this functionality.

You use index update strategies to maintain indexes. You can configure each index with a unique set of index update strategies. You should not specify more than three update strategies per index for performance reasons.

Sitecore provides a varied set of index update strategies, and you can extend this set with more strategies.

All the strategies that are delivered with Sitecore are defined under the following node in the Sitecore.ContentSearch.Solr.Index.IndexName configuration files:

```xml
<configuration ref="contentSearch/indexConfigurations/defaultSolrIndexConfiguration" />
    <strategies hint="list:AddStrategy">
```

You need to use of these default strategies:

```
  RebuildAfterFullPublish
  OnPublishEndAsync
```

More information about search, indexing and crawling you can find here:

https://doc.sitecore.net/sitecore_experience_platform/setting_up__maintaining/search_and_indexing